# Image getting stretched when adding frame to it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a cropped image & i display it on ui.When i add frame to it then image size is changed. for eg.if image size is 200*50 & when i add another image it on as a frame then the new image becomes equal height & width of the frame image. How can I get the solution for this?

**Here is my code:**

```
-(void)addFrames:(int)count
{
    float scale ;
    UIImage *borderImage;

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] == YES && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.00)
    {
        // RETINA DISPLAY
        scale = 2.0;
    }
    else
    {
        // non - retina display
        scale = 1.0;
    }
    if(count==1)
    {
         borderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];

    }
    else if(count==2)
    {
         borderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"borderImage1.png"];

    }
    else if(count==3)
    {
        borderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"borderImage2.png"];

    }
    else if(count==4)
    {
        borderImage =[UIImage imageNamed:@"borderImage3.png"];

    }
    else if(count==5)
    {
        borderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"borderImage4.png"];


    }

    UIImage *bottomImage = self.mainImage; //background image
    UIImage *image       = borderImage; //foreground image
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.img_background.frame.size.width, self.img_background.frame.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

    // Use existing opacity as is
    [bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    // Apply supplied opacity if applicable
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();//
    self.img_background.image=newImage;
    framedImage=newImage;

}
```

I want the new framed image to be of equal size as it was before adding the frame?

Answer (score 0):

You are the one who is saying:

```
[bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
```

That stretches the image to fill this rect, so it is `newSize.width` by `newSize.height`. If that isn't what you want, then don't do that. It draws where you tell it to draw at the size you tell to it to draw.